# Combinar array de alternativas com array da questão php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, array

Minha duvida é a seguinte: Tenho esse codigo jquery onde eu capturo todas as questoes de uma prova e logo abaixo as alternativas da mesma; porém não consigo relacionar as alternativas com as questões, alguém pode me ajudar, já tentei de tudo eu acho.

segue html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<li><textarea name="quest[]" placeholder="Digite seu texto aqui." required=""></textarea>
<input type="text" id="quest1" name="alternativa[]" value="a)" required="">
<input type="text" id="quest1" name="alternativa[]" value="b)" required=""></li>

<li><textarea name="quest[]" placeholder="Digite seu texto aqui." required=""></textarea>
<input type="text" id="quest2" name="alternativa[]" value="a)" required="">
<input type="text" id="quest2" name="alternativa[]" value="b)" required="">
<input type="text" id="quest2" name="alternativa[]" value="c)" required=""></li></form>

$("body").on('click', 'button[name="enviaProva"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var textarea = [];        
    var input = [];


    $('textarea[name="quest[]"]').each(function () {
        textarea.push($(this).val());
        $(this).parent().children('input[name="alternativa[]"]').each(function () {
            input.push($(this).val());
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/enviaProva.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {questao: textarea, alternativa: input},
        success: function (res) {

        }
    });
});
```

o resultado esperado no php seria:

```
$questao = isset($_POST['questao']) ? $_POST['questao'] : "";
$alternativa = isset($_POST['alternativa']) ? $_POST['alternativa'] : "";
```

se eu der um var_dump no $questao me retorna:

```
array(2) {[0]=> string(12) "primeira questao" [1]=> string(12) "segunda questao"}
```

no $alternativa me retorna:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "a)" [1]=> string(2) "b)" [2]=> string(2) "a)" [3]=> string(2) "b)" [4]=> string(2) "c)" }
```

sendo que as alternativas da primeira questao são "a)" e "b)".
E as da segunda questao são "a)", "b)" e "C)"

não estou conseguindo relacionar os dois arrays dentro do php.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do formato que pretendes obter? Ver o HTML seria muito útil também...

Comment: atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Tem como colocar também o html referente a uma pergunta e respestivas alternativas ?

Comment: ok vou colocar.

Comment: adicionei o html de exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes criar uma array onde cada pergunta é um objeto com o formato

```
{
  pergunta: 'texto',
  alternativas: [
    'altern 1',
    'altern x'
  ]
}
```

Podes obter isso assim:

```js
$("body").on('click', 'button[name="enviaProva"]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const perguntas = $('textarea[name="quest[]"]').get().map(function(el) {
    const alternativas = $(el)
      .parent()
      .children('input[name="alternativa[]"]')
      .get()
      .map(function(input) {
        return input.value;
      });

    return {
      pergunta: el.value,
      alternativas: alternativas
    };
  });
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(perguntas));

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/enviaProva.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: perguntas,
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <li><textarea name="quest[]" placeholder="Digite seu texto aqui." required=""></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="quest1" name="alternativa[]" value="a)" required="">
    <input type="text" id="quest1" name="alternativa[]" value="b)" required=""></li>

  <li><textarea name="quest[]" placeholder="Digite seu texto aqui." required=""></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="quest2" name="alternativa[]" value="a)" required="">
    <input type="text" id="quest2" name="alternativa[]" value="b)" required="">
    <input type="text" id="quest2" name="alternativa[]" value="c)" required=""></li>
</form>
<button name="enviaProva">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: olá amigo nao consegui implementar desse jeito, eu atualizei a questao mais uma vez espero que possa me ajudar.

Comment: @JoséRobertoJuliana vi agora o código que adicionaste. No PHP queres tratar as perguntas uma a uma ou queres enviar todas de uma vez e a resposta ser relacionada com todas?

Comment: então preciso relacionar uma a uma para poder inserir no banco, cada questao com suas alternativas

Comment: @JoséRobertoJuliana ok, mas queres enviar uma a uma do cliente para o servidor/PHP ou queres ter tudo numa array no PHP e tratar os dados no PHP/Servidor?

Comment: @JoséRobertoJuliana corrigi um erro na minha resposta, testa agora.

Comment: ok vou testar agora.

Comment: então Sergio, o seu codigo funcionou uma parte, ele obtém as alternativas na sequencia desejada, porém não retorna as questões, questões undefined.

Comment: @JoséRobertoJuliana testa o meu código como está na resposta (podes correr o exemplo e clicar no botão lá). O que a consola mostra é o que procuras?

Comment: olá Sergio, sim é 50% da solução, só não sei como passar também as questões, esse "pergunta: this.value" não funciona aqui

Comment: tem como passar também as perguntas, só está passando as alternativas.

Comment: @JoséRobertoJuliana corrigi, devia ser `el.value` em vez de `this.value`. Tentar ajudar à noite quando devia estar a dormir não é o ideal :)

Comment: você pode me ajudar como receber os dados no php para guardar no banco?

Answer (score 0):

Olá agradeço ao pessoal pela ajuda em especial ao moderador Sergio eu consegui passar tudo para o PHP, tanto as questões, como as alternativas e ficou assim:

```
    $("body").on('click', 'button[name="enviaProva"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var textarea = [];

    var perguntas = $('textarea[name="quest[]"]').get().map(function (el) {
        var alternativas = $(el)
                .parent()
                .children('input[name="alternativa[]"]')
                .get()
                .map(function (input) {
                    return input.value;
                });
        return {
            perguntas: el.value,
            alternativas: alternativas
        };
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/enviaProva.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {perguntas: perguntas},
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Desse modo eu recupero os dados no PHP:

```
$questao = isset($_POST['perguntas']) ? $_POST['perguntas'] : "";
var_dump($questao);
```

e me retorna os valores:

```
    array(2) {
  ["perguntas"]=>
  string(8) "primeira"
  ["alternativas"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a)"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "b)"
  }
}
array(2) {
  ["perguntas"]=>
  string(7) "segunda"
  ["alternativas"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "a)"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "b)"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "c)"
  }
}
```

agora como eu faço a inserção no banco, usando o foreach ele me retorna um novo array, como ficaria a inserção no banco nesse caso?